# MediaPlayer function search for specific song

Tags: android, eclipse, media-player

I want to make an mp3 app in which the user gives a text and then it plays that song. So far, I have this function in mind:

```
public void searchSong(String x) {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.x);
mp.start();
}
```

where x is the name stored, But ofcourse this gives an error saying "x cannot be resolved or is not a field". How can I fix that? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your songs have already stored in a specific location of sdcard,you can get the uri of song file ,then use mp.setDataSource() to bind what will be played.

If you want to search songs by specific song name, you can use android.provider.MediaStore.The Media provider contains meta data for all available media on both internal and external storage devices include song name.

A simple query code snippet is like this:

```
public void searchSong(String songName) {
    final String[] projections = new String[] {
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
    final String selection = Media.TITLE + " = ?";
    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { songName };

    Cursor cursor = mContentResolver
            .query(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projections, selection, selectionArgs,
                    Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    if (cursor != null) {
        int indexFilePath = cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA);
        int indexArtist = cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.ARTIST);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // Get the informations of the song
            cursor.getString(indexArtist);
            cursor.getString(indexFilePath);

            // Then do what you want
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```